# How to add a local image file to an image field programatically

Tags: 8, files

I have serveral image files in the folder /sites/subsite.example.com/files/blog.dir/1/gallery1, and I need to add these files to a node programatically. I think this is the right code:

```
 use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
 use Drupal\file\Entity\File;

  $node = Node::load(1);
  $uri = 'public://image.jpg'; <--- this is my problem

  // check first if the file exists for the uri    
  $files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('file')
    ->loadByProperties(['uri' => $uri]);
  $file = reset($files);

  // if not create a file
  if (!$file) {
    $file = File::create([
      'uri' => $uri,
    ]);
    $file->save();
  }

  $node->field_image[] = [
    'target_id' => $file->id(),
    'alt' => 'Alt text',
    'title' => 'Title',
  ];

  $node->save();
```

What I don't know is how must be the $uri I need to put when my files are in a subdomain directory in a mulitsite drupal installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public://` is the `Public file system path` that you can set in `/admin/config/media/file-system`.

In your case it would probably be `sites/subsite.example.com/files`.

To get the image you must then use, `public://blog.dir/1/gallery1/image.jpg`, where `public://` is the same as `sites/subsite.example.com/files`.